# Perminately lock a formula to a range so owner cant even edit it

Tags: google-sheets, range, locking

Is there a way to lock a formula to a range besides using protected ranges? I don't want the owner to be able to edit the formula. Essentially, it's a barcode generator and staff keeps deleting it. I have it in a protected range, however, the people who are deleting it are the owners. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to protect the entire sheet except where the staff should edit the values? You can even allow specific people to edit it

Comment: The staff has to use the owner account because google sheets only runs scripts for the owner

Comment: I tried making a new spreadsheet. I shared it to another account I have as editor. I restricted the entire sheet except a single cell (only I can edit). I added a formula that uses a Google Apps Script function. When editing with the other user the formula is being recalculated every time. Still couldn't edit the formula or the other cells. Could you try doing that in a new spreadhseet?

Comment: The person who is editing it is the owner so that wouldnt work. you cant restrict the owner which is what I'm trying to do

Comment: What I was suggesting was to create another account for the staff. Also, if the functions/formulas do not execute for the editors, that's likely a bug and you should probably notify Google using [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) (Note that I don't know what are you doing in the function/formula).